# Vuejs components not getting displayed

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've a `password_reset.vue` script as below:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="form.errors.has('photo')">
            @{{ form.errors.get('photo') }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="label">Current Password</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="field--wrapper">
                    <label for="current_password">Current Password</label>
                    <input class="nom-fields" type="password"
                           v-model="form.current_password"
                           id="current_password" name="current_password"
                           placeholder="Current Password" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="label">Repeat Password</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="field--wrapper">
                    <label for="password_repeat">Repeat Password</label>
                    <input class="nom-fields" type="password"
                           v-model="form.password_repeat"

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9 text-right">
                <button id="change_password"
                        class="blue-btn" v-on:click="update">
                    Change Password
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                form: new MyForm({
                    current_password: '',
                    new_password: '',
                    password_repeat: '',
                    message: ''
                })
            };
        },

        methods: {
            /**
             * Update the user's password.
             */
            update(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                this.form.startProcessing();

                this.$http.post('/account/change_password', this.form)
                        .then(function(response) {

                            this.form.finishProcessing();
                        })
                        .catch(function(response) {
                            this.form.setErrors(response.data);
                        });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

and in my `bootstrap.js` file, I've:

```
import './interceptors.js';
import './forms/form.js';
import './forms/errors.js';

import PasswordReset from './settings/password_reset.vue'

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        PasswordReset
    },
    ready() {

    }
});
```

and in the `app.js` file I've:

```
import './bootstrap.js'
```

HTML:

```
<body>
     <password-reset></password-reset>
</body>
```

But it seems the component is not getting displayed.  I tried to alert a msg in the ready method and it's working fine. I'm loading Vue.js also.

Comment: Could it be because your html is invalid? You have a </div> closing a <body> tag

Comment: @TremendusApps: No, that was a typo from myside when I added the question in SO.

Comment: What do you see in the Vue devtools in the browser?

Comment: @ceejayoz: for some weird reasons, I'm not able to see the Vue devtool plugin in inspect element :/

Comment: @user1012181 IMO that points to more serious issues. What does the final rendered JS for the app look like? Does it look like your components are making it in properly?

Comment: yes, seems like rendering is working

Comment: How are you importing the Vue library into your project?

Comment: I'm importing the library using https link from cdnjs